# What exactly the meaning of this rule regarding Or patterns? "Ill formed if the type of the expression fragment does not unify with p_i | q_i..."

Tags: rust

> When type checking an expression `match e_s { a_1 => e_1, ... a_n => e_n }`, for each match arm `a_i` which contains a pattern of form `p_i | q_i`, the pattern `p_i | q_i` is considered ill formed if, at the depth `d` where it exists the fragment of `e_s` at depth `d`, the type of the expression fragment does not unify with `p_i | q_i`.

From [Patterns – The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/patterns.html#or-patterns)

I tried to create an example for such ill formed case, my approach was this

```rust
fn main() {
    let v = 10;

    match v {
        1 | 2 => 2.0,
        3 | 4 => 4.0,
        5 | 6 => 6.0,
        _ => 0.0,
    };
}
```

But this is valid, and why wouldn't be? I might just don't understand. Why should the arm or pattern type unify with the expression type? Or what exactly do they mean by unify?

What would be a correct example to show the validity of the above-quoted rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea of the paragraph, is that the part of the object that you match, and the matching condition should always match in type, even if you match some deep part of the object, e.g. this example has 2 valid branches and 1 invalid (last), because type of `Some(42) | Some(43)` is `Option<i32>`, while this pattern matches against `Option<A>` part of type `B`.

```
struct A(i32);
struct B(Option<A>);

fn main(){
    let b = B(Some(A(42)));
    match b {
        B(Some(A(42) | A(43))) => println!("ok 1"),
        B(Some(A(42)) | None) => println!("ok 2"),
        B(Some(42) | Some(43)) => println!("err"),
    }
}
```

Comment: Good approach, but I originally ruled out similar solution because of "Given a pattern p | q at some depth for some arbitrary patterns p and q, the pattern is considered ill-formed if the type inferred for p does not unify with the type inferred for q". I think your example is proving this rather than what is in the question. Because in the question the expression also mentioned and play a role regarding the type unification.

Comment: @Eraklon I think you refer to e.g. `Some(42) | Some(A(42))`, it's a bit different

Comment: Hmm I see, then indeed you are right that your example shows that if one arm type does not match the others, then there is a problem. The thing what confuse me is that why `e_s` is even mentioned or any other `e_i`? In your example those are just println-s and are irrelevant, since all the "action" happens in the arms pattern.

Comment: Ohh never mind I see that `e_s` it self is the scrutinee and not the expressions of the arms body.